# Redirecting an already redirected page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

```
RewriteRule ^teamstore/(.*)/$ /teamproduct.php?teamproduct=$1&products=true [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^teamstore-(.*)/$ /teamproduct.php?teamproduct=$1&products=true [NC,L]
```

Here's the situation.  We've already had theese urls rewritten, but we want to change the formatting of these pages so they're separated by hyphen instead of a slash.

I tried redirectmatch but this added additional php value parameters to the end of the urls.  It came out to be

```
RedirectMatch 301 /teamstore/(.*) http://www.domainname.com/teamstore-$1/
```

Here was the result...

```
teamstore-valuehere//?teamproduct=2352323&productes=true
```

I want someone who types in the original address teamstore/info/ to get directed to teamstore-info/ - Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

The main reason is to avoid duplicate content issues with existing links in Google Search Results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of the rules can matter, but if you want to 301 redirect the initial request for SEO reasons, then I would change your RewiteRules to the following.

```
RewriteRule ^teamstore/(.*)/$ teamstore-$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teamstore-(.*)/$ /teamproduct.php?teamproduct=$1&products=true [NC,L]
```

This will first translate `teamstore/info/` to `teamstore-info/` and send the appropriate 301 response. Upon second pass it will redirect to the php you want.

Note, this is not ideal as far as performance. Yet, it does accomplish the goal of making Google happy.

Comment: This isn't redirecting the initial redirect.  It's displaying teamstore/ without any redirects or any php data.  I'm using wordpress so this may be the result of some backend issue, I'm going to double and triple check this now, but I don't think anything should be out of place.  - Do I need to restart apache?  My assumption is no since changes were made, but they're not the expected changes, lol.

Comment: I updated the code, give it another try. However, WordPress has it's own ReWriteRules. You may need to use them.

Comment: Thanks - we have a custom plugin we developed so that we don't use wordpresses rules, but the .htaccess file, I'll give this one a shot.  Thanks again!

Comment: When I added another slash - I got it to work - RewriteRule ^teamstore/(.*)/$ teamstore-$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teamstore-(.*)/$ /teamproduct.php?teamproduct=$1&products=true [NC,L]

Comment: Sorry, yes, your trailing slash is required and I did not put it back. I have updated my answer. Thanks.